# Git equivalent for svn copy <URL> <URL>

Tags: git, svn

I need to import an external git project to my private repo. Can I do it from server to server without needing to import the external project to local machine and push it to the server?

In svn I can achieve this by using svn cp   as a server to server command.

Comment: Are you looking for http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule ?

Answer (score 0):

If your server has a terminal and has git installed, you can do what you do on your local machine on your server too.

Comment: Actually I don't have ssh access to the server. I only have access to the git repo on the server. What I want to do is, copy an existing project repo to the fresh git repo on the server.